# Got a Git error while trying to clone it, how do I fix this?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to clone a Azure DevOps team project to my laptop, but it failed with the following error.

> Git failed with a fatal error. unable to access 'https://myrepo.visualstudio.com/My Team Project/_git/My Team Project/'. The requested URL returned error:400

I don't know how to resolve this. I've not had this problem before.

Comment: How do you get the link for clone?

Comment: I was doing this without Visual Studio 2017, so didn't have a link to clone.

Comment: Could it be because I have spaces in the URL?

Comment: I think the embedded spaces in the URL did help contribute to the problem. Thank you m.alban.

Comment: Yes, It might be.

Answer (score 0):

Copy clone URL and use that URL to clone the repository. The format should be like;

```
https://xxx.visualstudio.com/ Git%200817%20%20space%20%20%20Test/_git/Git%200817%20%20space%20%20%20Test
```

[image: clone example]